# how to iterate over a list of variable length in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of values like:

```
list_of_values = ['clients':['add, view'], 'vendors': ['add', 'delete', 'change'], 'companies': ['add', 'view', 'delete', 'change']]
```

Using django template tags I have to make a template like:

```
Activities    ADD      |  VIEW      |  CHANGE      |  DELETE
clients      checkbox    checkbox     checkbox       checkbox
vendors      checkbox    checkbox     checkbox       checkbox
companies    checkbox    checkbox     checkbox       checkbox
```

Kindly let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

List of values looks more like a dictionary to me, assuming it is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Activities</th>
        <th>ADD</th>
        <th>VIEW</th>
        <th>CHANGE</th>
        <th>DELETE</th>
    </tr>
    {% for key in list_of_values %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td>
                {% if 'add' in list_of_values.key %}
                    <input type="checkbox" checked/>
                {% else %}
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if 'view' in list_of_values.key %}
                    <input type="checkbox" checked/>
                {% else %}
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if 'change' in list_of_values.key %}
                    <input type="checkbox" checked/>
                {% else %}
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if 'delete' in list_of_values.key %}
                    <input type="checkbox" checked/>
                {% else %}
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                {% endif %}
           </td>
        </tr>        
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```